# How do I pass variables to a PyQt class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

Before writing the Python code, I already made a ui file to made QT designer. The UI file has one Qlabel containing the values. To output an external value, I've tried, but I never could never make it. This is the My QtCode

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("untitled.ui")[0]

class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self, name):
        self.hello.setText("Hello. %s"%name)

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = WindowClass()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I want to accept the name value in if__name__=="*main*_" and hand it over to the part that outputs the label of the Qt class. I am not that good at English.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to accept the name value in if__name__=="main_""?

Comment: name = input("Enter your name : ")
I want to pass the value of the outside name in the WindowClass.

Comment: You should normally avoid using terminal input for the UI (and it's usually not required). In any case, just add an argument to the init, like `def __init__(self, name):` and make it an instance attribute (`self.name = name`). I suggest you to do some careful research and studying on how functions, arguments, classes and instances work, as they are fundamental aspects of Python, object oriented programming, and programming in general.